# How to apply a sequence of functions on a sequence of variables in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, higher-order-functions

I have a function which takes a sequence of function and a sequence of arguments. This should return a vector with the results of each function applied to the sequence of the arguments.

```
((solution + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4) ;;--> [21 6 1]
```

Im trying to solve it with reduce but i dont know how to apply all functions it works only for the first function:

```
(defn solution
  [& args]
 (fn [& args2]
 (reduce (first args) [] args2)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`juxt`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/juxt):

```
((juxt + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4)
=> [21 6 1]
```

Or define function `solution`:

```
(defn solution
  [& args]
  (fn [& args2]
    (apply (apply juxt args) args2)))

((solution + max min) 2 3 5 1 6 4)
=> [21 6 1]
```

Comment: Well, `(def solution juxt)` would do to define `solution`.